# Updating Realm object with Nil not working

Tags: swift, uiimage, realm

How can I update Realm object with nil? The image recovers after users delete the Image, and save on the app with Swift5. The object value wasn't changed when I tried to set 'nil' to the Realm object directly for debugging like this.

```
realm.beginWrite()
let m = realm.objects(Inventory.self).filter("id == %@", detailId as Any).first
m!.image = nil
try! realm.commitWrite()
```

//  Inventory.swift

```
class Inventory: Object {
@objc dynamic var number: Int = 1

//ID
@objc dynamic var id = 0

//Image
@objc dynamic private var imageData: Data? = nil 
dynamic private var _image: UIImage? = nil  

dynamic var image: UIImage? {
    set{
        self._image = newValue
        if let value = newValue {
            self.imageData = value.pngData() as Data?
        }
    }
    get{
        if let image = self._image {
            return image
        }
        if let data = self.imageData {
            self._image = UIImage(data: data as Data)
            return self._image
        }
        return nil
    }
} }
```

Comment: I posted an answer but for clarity, Realm does not have image objects. It only supports the following types: Boolean Bool, Integral types Int, Int8, Int16, Int32, Int64, Decimal128, Double, String, Date, Data, ObjectId, User-defined Object-derived types
and List as outlined in this section of the docs [Object Model](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/ios/objects/#object-model)

Comment: Sorry, it was Data objects for the image.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I updated my answer with a solution. Keep in mind that Realm is not well-suited to store large images (thumbnails are fine) as stated in the documentation several times. If you're storing larger images, another service like [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage) is preferred and store a reference to that URL in Realm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the code in the question is how the Inventory objects image property is being set to nil.

When this happens

```
m!.image = nil
```

It's setting the unmanaged `image` property to nil

```
set {
   self._image = newValue
   if let value = newValue {
      self.imageData = value.pngData() as Data?
   }
}
```

But as you can see with the if statement within set, if the value is nil, it's ignored, so `self.imageData` is never set to nil

There are a lot of solutions but since all of those vars are optionals, probably the simplest is to just let it be nil within the set

```
set {
   self._image = newValue
   self.imageData = newValue.pngData() as Data?
}
```

**EDIT**

the below is the original answer but once more data was added the the question it was not complete.

Only optional properties can be set to nil. So they need to be defined in a special way in realm, like this for a String object

```
class Inventory: Object {
   @objc dynamic var id = ""
   @objc dynamic var imageName: String? = nil  //or NSData/Data
   //or for numbers, use this let value = RealmOptional<Int>()
   ...
```

then to set the optional to nil something like this is a safe way to do it

```
let detailId = "some detail id"
if let item = realm.objects(Inventory.self).filter("id == %@", detailId).first {
    try! realm.write {
        item.imageName = nil
    }
} else {
  print("item not found")
}
```

Comment: It caused another error, but I got what you meant, so I solved the problem I asked. Thank you for teaching me about Realm as well.